# kubedns container restarts endlessly

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to get kubedns to work on my cluster but can't seem to get it to run. It keeps getting restarted because the `healthz` container keeps getting a failure on resolving `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Output of `kubedns` logs:

```
I0613 17:55:50.490883       1 dns.go:42] version: v1.6.0-alpha.0.680+3872cb93abf948-dirty
I0613 17:55:50.491791       1 server.go:107] Using https://k8s.internal for kubernetes master, kubernetes API: <nil>
I0613 17:55:50.691495       1 server.go:63] ConfigMap not configured, using values from command line flags
I0613 17:55:50.691539       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
I0613 17:55:50.691564       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-map=""
I0613 17:55:50.691573       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --config-map-namespace="kube-system"
I0613 17:55:50.691586       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --dns-bind-address="0.0.0.0"
I0613 17:55:50.691591       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
I0613 17:55:50.691600       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
I0613 17:55:50.691612       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --federations=""
I0613 17:55:50.691618       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
I0613 17:55:50.691622       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --kube-master-url="https://k8s.internal"
I0613 17:55:50.691626       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --kubecfg-file="/etc/kubernetes/worker-kubeconfig.yaml"
I0613 17:55:50.691630       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
I0613 17:55:50.691636       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-dir=""
I0613 17:55:50.691650       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
I0613 17:55:50.691659       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
I0613 17:55:50.691667       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
I0613 17:55:50.691672       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --v="0"
I0613 17:55:50.691677       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --version="false"
I0613 17:55:50.691691       1 server.go:113] FLAG: --vmodule=""
I0613 17:55:50.691767       1 server.go:155] Starting SkyDNS server (0.0.0.0:10053)
I0613 17:55:50.691866       1 server.go:167] Skydns metrics not enabled
I0613 17:55:50.691967       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0613 17:55:50.691984       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0613 17:55:50.790263       1 server.go:126] Setting up Healthz Handler (/readiness)
I0613 17:55:50.791070       1 server.go:131] Setting up cache handler (/cache)
I0613 17:55:50.791096       1 server.go:120] Status HTTP port 8081
I0613 17:56:49.437868       1 server.go:150] Ignoring signal terminated (can only be terminated by SIGKILL)
```

Output of `healthz`:

```
2017/06/13 17:53:09 Healthz probe on /healthz error: Result of last exec: nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local': Name does not resolve
, at 2017-06-13 17:53:08.890210169 +0000 UTC, error exit status 1
```

The weird thing is if I `exec` that very same lookup against the `kubedns` container it succeeds:

```
$ kubectl --namespace kube-system exec kube-dns-v15-8nx4h -c kubedns -- nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost
Server:    127.0.0.1
Address 1: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Name:      kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 172.17.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

But on the `dnsmasq` container it doesn't:

```
$ kubectl --namespace kube-system exec kube-dns-v15-8nx4h -c dnsmasq -- nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost
nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local': Name does not resolve
Server:    127.0.0.1
Address 1: 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

I also don't see it do service discovery to add records, but I'm not sure if that's just because it doesn't have time to with the healthcheck killing it before it has the chance.

Here is the replication controller definition:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "metadata": {
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "kube-dns",
      "kubernetes.io/cluster-service": "true",
      "version": "v15"
    },
    "name": "kube-dns-v15",
    "namespace": "kube-system"
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "k8s-app": "kube-dns",
      "version": "v15"
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "k8s-app": "kube-dns",
          "kubernetes.io/cluster-service": "true",
          "version": "v15"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "ssl-certs",
            "hostPath": {
              "path": "/usr/share/ca-certificates"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "kubeconfig",
            "hostPath": {
              "path": "/etc/kubernetes/worker-kubeconfig.yaml"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "etc-kube-ssl",
            "hostPath": {
              "path": "/etc/kubernetes/ssl"
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "mountPath": "/etc/ssl/certs",
                "name": "ssl-certs",
                "readOnly": true
              },
              {
                "mountPath": "/etc/kubernetes/worker-kubeconfig.yaml",
                "name": "kubeconfig",
                "readOnly": true
              },
              {
                "mountPath": "/etc/kubernetes/ssl",
                "name": "etc-kube-ssl",
                "readOnly": true
              }
            ],
            "args": [
              "--domain=cluster.local.",
              "--dns-port=10053",
              "--kube-master-url=https://k8s.internal",
              "--kubecfg-file=/etc/kubernetes/worker-kubeconfig.yaml"
            ],
            "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64:1.9",
            "livenessProbe": {
              "failureThreshold": 5,
              "httpGet": {
                "path": "/healthz",
                "port": 8080,
                "scheme": "HTTP"
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 60,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "timeoutSeconds": 5
            },
            "name": "kubedns",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 10053,
                "name": "dns-local",
                "protocol": "UDP"
              },
              {
                "containerPort": 10053,
                "name": "dns-tcp-local",
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "readinessProbe": {
              "httpGet": {
                "path": "/readiness",
                "port": 8081,
                "scheme": "HTTP"
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 30,
              "timeoutSeconds": 5
            },
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "100m",
                "memory": "200Mi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "100m",
                "memory": "50Mi"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "args": [
              "--cache-size=1000",
              "--no-resolv",
              "--server=127.0.0.1#10053"
            ],
            "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/kube-dnsmasq-amd64:1.4.1",
            "name": "dnsmasq",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 53,
                "name": "dns",
                "protocol": "UDP"
              },
              {
                "containerPort": 53,
                "name": "dns-tcp",
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "args": [
              "-cmd=nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:10053 >/dev/null",
              "-port=8080",
              "-quiet"
            ],
            "image": "gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz-amd64:v1.2.0",
            "name": "healthz",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "10m",
                "memory": "20Mi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "10m",
                "memory": "20Mi"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "dnsPolicy": "Default"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using minikube? DNS right now seems to be f**cked with minikube.

Comment: No this is a custom install on AWS using Terraform and CoreOS.

Comment: I have seen this kind of issue, it network is not configured properly. check and see you overlay network configuration, node default routes etc.

Comment: @sfgroups I thought that as well, but I had that problem initially with kube-proxy. I wasn't able to exec or tail logs from another node. I figured out that my AWS security groups had the flannel ports blocked. Once I fixed that kube-proxy was working correctly, but then this problem came up.